# Generating random doubles in different ranges

Tags: c++, performance, random, c++11

In my program I need to generate random doubles repeatedly (millions of times) and there are several variables with flat distributions, but different ranges. Currently this is what I do:

```
double w, v, k;
double wmax = 0.5;
double vmax = 1.0;

std::random_device rd;
std::default_random_engine dre(rd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> wRand(-wmax, wmax);
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> vRand(-vmax, vmax);
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> kRand(0.0, 1.0);

w = wRand(dre);
v = vRand(dre);
k = kRand(dre);
```

Is this a proper way, OR having one distribution and constructing all the numbers from it is better? I'm extremely cautious of performance issues and I feel like having one distribution and a couple of arithmetic operations on it would be quicker. Will it? What about the comparative quality of random numbers in such case?

Comment: Don't worry about performance issues until they're issues. Focus only on correctness of your program before then.

Comment: @Patashu I don't want to write half-page of prehistory etc. Program works perfectly well, I've optimized all the essential things in it. This random generation is pretty influential time-spender and I don't want to screw it up.

Comment: Are you generating each of the w,v,k vars on each loop invocation or does it vary how often each is generated?

Comment: First two numbers in one loop, but generated different number of times (second is less, depending on the values in first). Third number is in another independent loop.

Comment: Doubles have an awful lot of precision, needing many bits of randomness. Maybe you can get away with a worse but faster RNG.

Comment: @maxy, would there be an option for less precise quicker generator which will cast to double? I do need double precision variables at the end, but don't care about the random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a single distribution with three arithmetic operations to scale them appropriately.  It will use less memory and the arithmetic operations will be fast.

But your overall performance will be more driven by how you structure your loops and minimize branch misprediction.  [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the link, I've done a lot of read on that topic recently but haven't seen that question. Looks useful! But I think I've optimized whatever I could in that area, this question is maybe more about good programming practices. I'd say that the current form looks a bit ugly to me, but inserting arithmetic expressions instead of a simple random generator looks bulky...

Comment: Well I would put the arithmetic expressions inside of inlined functions or macros.